# How can I permanently change the style of my object?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

```
#one
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 325px;
}
```

Given the css codes above I would like to move my image downwards. I want it to move 4px everytime I click a button.

```
function lol(){
    document.getElementById("one").style.top = 100px;
}
```

and the usual:

```
<button onClick="lol">
```

What it does is move the image above, and when i change 100px to another value it just moves it there. I want the outcome position to be permanent and when I click a button, it moves that specific px downward if negative, upward if positive, and clicking it again makes it move as follows, with respect to its 2nd position, not the original. Is there a possible way that I can use without using other methods like jQuery which I am not familiar with.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure. Get the value then add 4px to it.

Comment: ohhh thaaanks! I suck at this hahaha

Comment: `<button onClick="lol">` won't do anything.

Comment: Oops sorry about that lol()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you're missing the `()` on your call:

```
<button onClick="lol()">
```

(`onClick` is also `onclick` in the spec [lower-case `c`], but browsers allow `onClick` as well.)

Then, in the function, get the current value, convert it to a number (ignoring the `px` at the end), and assign the result back:

```
function lol(){
    var oneStyle = document.getElementById("one").style;
    var top = parseInt(oneStyle.top, 10);
    oneStyle.top = (top + 100) + "px";
}
```

`parseInt` will parse the number at the beginning of the string, and stop when it reaches the `px`.

**Live Example:**

```js
function lol() {
  var oneStyle = document.getElementById("one").style;
  var top = parseInt(oneStyle.top, 10);
  oneStyle.top = (top + 100) + "px";
}
```

```html
<button onClick="lol()">Click me</button>
<div id="one" style="position: absolute; top: 40px; left: 10px">I'm one</div>
```

Note, though, that that assumes you've used an **inline** style for `top` in the first place, not (for instance) a value from a stylesheet or just the natural position of the element.

To use a stylesheet value or the natural position of the element, you need `getComputedStyle` (or `currentStyle` on old IE):

```
function lol(){
    var one = document.getElementById("one");
    var style = window.getComputedStyle ? window.getComputedStyle(one) : one.currentStyle;
    var top = parseInt(style.top, 10);
    one.style.top = (top + 100) + "px";
}
```

**Live Example:**

```js
function lol(){
    var one = document.getElementById("one");
    var style = window.getComputedStyle ? window.getComputedStyle(one) : one.currentStyle;
    var top = parseInt(style.top, 10);
    one.style.top = (top + 100) + "px";
}
```

```css
#one {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="lol()">Click me</button>
<div id="one">I'm one</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that the `onClick` method doesn't even work. +1

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, get the current offset of the button and add 4px to it. However there are number of small issues to be aware of. See this working example:

```js
var delta = 4;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var button = document.getElementById('my-button');
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var offset = parseInt(button.style.top) || 0;
    button.style.top = (offset + delta) + 'px';
  });
});
```

```css
#my-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<button id="my-button">Button</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to use the += operator.

```
function lol(){
   var x = document.getElementById("one").style.top
   x = (x+100)+'px'
}
```

Comment: No, that will give `NaN100px`.

Comment: yep just realised that